# Returning an instance of tinyMCE when initialised

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is it possible to make this function return textEditor via the `oninit` callback? I attempted to pass `textEditor` as a parameter to `initialised()` but only got undefined.

```
function magic() {

    var returnMe;

    function initialised() {
        console.log('initialised');
        //tried to set returnMe here, textEditor undefined! what!
    }



    var textEditor = new tinymce.Editor(element, {

        ...

        oninit : initialised(),

        ...

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is easy:

```
function initialised() {
    console.log('initialised');
}

function magic() {

    var returnMe;

    var textEditor = new tinymce.Editor(element, {

        ...

        oninit : initialised(),

        ...

        }
    });

}
```